# Deleting rows of data using nested if statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data from a database, and I need to count the rows of data. The data is sorted by number, and then each number could have multiple sets, designated by a counter.

Row;    Num;   Cnt

1;    356;   1

2;    357;   1

3;    357;   1

4;    357;   2

In this set of data, I need to remove the entirety of Row(3) so that I do not count (357-1) twice. I would like to compare Num(x) to Num(x-1), determine if they are equal, and if they are, I want to compare Cnt(x) to Cnt(x-1). If that value is also equal, I would like to delete Row(x).

Row;    Num;   Cnt

1;    356;   1

2;    357;   1

3;    357;   2

Comment: use Remove Duplicates, it is on the data tab.  A formula in itself will not delete rows.

Comment: Thank you, I was making more of an issue of this than was necessary. I appreciate the response.